# React, Printing the state of an array and updating state on button press

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to print the log array when one of the buttons are pressed. How can I update a state in React and print it to the screen when one of the buttons are pressed without making multiple print-outs?

This is supposed to function as a sort of datalog, much like the console but needs to be on rendered on the page.

As of now everything else works and the buttons call functions that push the generation results to the log array.

```
const desert = [
  { content: "Goblin, Cave Bat, Goblin" },
  { content: "Ahriman" },
  { content: "Desertpede, Desert Sahagin" },
  { content: "Antlion, Antlion, Antlion" },
  { content: "No Encounter" },
  { content: "No Encounter" },
  { content: "No Encounter" }
];

const forest = [
  { content: "Hindlegs, Axebeak, Hindlegs" },
  { content: "Arachne" },
  { content: "Bood Eye, Flan" },
  { content: "Bomb, Bomb, Bomb" },
  { content: "No Encounter" },
  { content: "No Encounter" },
  { content: "No Encounter" }
];

const goblin = [
  { content: "ATK 1" },
  { content: "ATK 2" },
  { content: "ATK 3" },
  { content: "ATK 4" },
  { content: "ATK 5" },
  { content: "ATK 6" },
  { content: "Miss" }
];

const arachne = [
  { content: "ATK 1" },
  { content: "ATK 2" },
  { content: "ATK 3" },
  { content: "ATK 4" },
  { content: "ATK 5" },
  { content: "ATK 6" },
  { content: "Miss" }
];

const log = [];

class DesertGenerator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ""
    };

    this.desertGeneration = this.desertGeneration.bind(this);
  }

  desertGeneration() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * desert.length);

    let generation = desert[number].content;

    this.setState({ content: generation });

    log.push(generation);
    console.log(log);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DesertButton
        handleDesertGeneration={this.desertGeneration}
        generation={this.state.content}
      />
    );
  }
}

class ForestGenerator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ""
    };

    this.forestGeneration = this.forestGeneration.bind(this);
  }

  forestGeneration() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * forest.length);

    let generation = forest[number].content;

    this.setState({ content: generation });

    log.push(generation);
    console.log(log);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ForestButton
        handleForestGeneration={this.forestGeneration}
        generation={this.state.content}
      />
    );
  }
}

class GoblinGenerator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ""
    };

    this.goblinGeneration = this.goblinGeneration.bind(this);
  }

  goblinGeneration() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * goblin.length);

    let generation = goblin[number].content;

    this.setState({ content: generation });

    log.push(generation);
    console.log(log);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GoblinButton
        handleGoblinGeneration={this.goblinGeneration}
        generation={this.state.content}
      />
    );
  }
}

class ArachneGenerator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ""
    };

    this.arachneGeneration = this.arachneGeneration.bind(this);
  }

  arachneGeneration() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * arachne.length);

    let generation = arachne[number].content;

    this.setState({ content: generation });

    log.push(generation);
    console.log(log);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ArachneButton
        handleArachneGeneration={this.arachneGeneration}
        generation={this.state.content}
      />
    );
  }
}

class DesertButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        id="Desert"
        className="btn"
        onClick={this.props.handleDesertGeneration}
      >
        Desert
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class ForestButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        id="Forest"
        className="btn"
        onClick={this.props.handleForestGeneration}
      >
        Forest
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class GoblinButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        id="Goblin"
        className="btn"
        onClick={this.props.handleGoblinGeneration}
      >
        Goblin
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class ArachneButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        id="Arachne"
        className="btn"
        onClick={this.props.handleArachneGeneration}
      >
        Arachne
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DesertGenerator />
    <ForestGenerator />
    <GoblinGenerator />
    <ArachneGenerator />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("content")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, but I believe this does what you want.

I reduced a lot of your components because they were repetitive. I also used [PropTypes](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) to ensure consistency in `state`/`prop` declaration and usage (basically, you can't pass a `string` down from a `parent` and attempt to invoke it in the `child` as if it were a `function` -- strings remain strings, functions remain functions, ...etc -- regardless of how many times they were passed down).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/qvyw4yv36

**components/Content.js**

```
export const content = {
  desert: [
    "Goblin, Cave Bat, Goblin",
    "Ahriman",
    "Desertpede, Desert Sahagin",
    "Antlion, Antlion, Antlion",
    "No Encounter",
    "No Encounter",
    "No Encounter"
  ],
  forest: [
    "Hindlegs, Axebeak, Hindlegs",
    "Arachne",
    "Bood Eye, Flan",
    "Bomb, Bomb, Bomb",
    "No Encounter",
    "No Encounter",
    "No Encounter"
  ],
  goblin: ["ATK 1", "ATK 2", "ATK 3", "ATK 4", "ATK 5", "ATK 6", "Miss"],
  arachne: ["ATK 1", "ATK 2", "ATK 3", "ATK 4", "ATK 5", "ATK 6", "Miss"]
};

export const contentTypes = ["desert", "forest", "goblin", "arachne"];

export const logTypes = [
  { title: "Generation Log", type: "generation" },
  { title: "Actions Log", type: "actions" },
  { title: "Actions Log (by type)", type: "actionsByType" }
];
```

**components/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Generator from "./Generator";
import Logger from "./Logger";
import { content, contentTypes, logTypes } from "./Content";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    generation: {},
    actions: [],
    actionsByType: [],
    count: 0
  };

  logGeneration = (id, generation) =>
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newCount = prevState.count + 1; // count of action (1, 2, ...etc)
      const nextAction = `action${newCount}`; // string used for action property (action1, action2, ...etc)

      return {
        generation: { ...prevState.generation, [id]: generation }, // spread out previous generation state, add the button's [id] as a property with the selected generation
        actions: {
          ...prevState.actions, // spread out previous actions state
          [nextAction]: generation // add the [nextAction] string as a property with the selected generation
        },
         actionsByType: {
          ...prevState.actionsByType, // spread out previous actionsByType state 
          [id]: { ...prevState.actionsByType[id], [nextAction]: generation } // select id (ex: ["forest"]) and spread out previous actionsByType state, and add a [nextAction] property with the selected generation (ex: "action1": "Miss")
        },
        count: newCount
      };
    });

  render = () => (
    <div className="app">
      {contentTypes.map(type => ( // map over contentTypes 
        <Generator
          key={type} // type as key
          id={type} // type as id
          content={content[type]} // type as a content selector
          logGeneration={this.logGeneration} // pass down logGeneration method
        />
      ))}
      {logTypes.map(({ type, ...props }) => ( // map over logType, pull out type, put the rest in props
        <Logger 
          {...props} // spread and pass down props
          key={type}  // use type as key
          log={this.state[type]} // use type for selection state (ex: this.state["actions"] || this.state.actions)
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**components/Generator.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Button from "../Button";

class Generator extends PureComponent {
  handleGeneration = id => {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.content.length); // grab random number between 0-6 

    const generation = this.props.content[number]; // grab content by index from passed in content array (ex: forest[0-6])

    this.props.logGeneration(id, generation); // pass back id and generation to the log method
  };

  render = () => (
    <Button id={this.props.id} onHandleClick={this.handleGeneration}>
      {this.props.id}
    </Button>
  );
}

export default Generator;

Generator.propTypes = {
  logGeneration: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  content: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired
};
```

**components/Button.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Button = ({ children, id, onHandleClick }) => (
  <div className="button-container">
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-primary"
      onClick={() => onHandleClick(id)} // pass back id on button click (ex: "forest")
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default Button;

Button.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onHandleClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

**components/Logger.js**

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Logger = ({ log, title }) =>
  !isEmpty(log) ? ( // if the log isn't empty...
    <div className="logger-container"> // show log
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center " }}>{title}</h1>
      <div className="log">
        <pre>
          <code>{JSON.stringify(log, null, 4)}</code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null; // else show nothing

export default Logger;

Logger.propTypes = {
  log: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string),
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string))
  ]),
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll definitely be looking through it!

Comment: No problem. It's a lot to take in, so if you have any questions, feel free to ask.